# Bar segmented control has padding in Toolbar on iOS7 iphone 5s real device

Tags: ios, iphone, uitoolbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I am running into an issue. The toolbar adds padding at front of iOS7 iphone 5s real device.

[image: error images];

however, the issue does not see on simulator nor iOS7 iphone 4s devices.

My configuration is as

[image: Ui Confguration]

Anyone can point out what might be wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even I faced the same issue (however, was seeing it in both simulator as well as device). I used `setWidth` message to limit the width of each segment. So, something like :-

```
[segmentedControl setWidth:75.0f forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

should solve this issue. I was not using storyboards though

Answer (score 1):

I'm not proud of this fix, but it does fix it for me:

```
// in the app delegate class
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

// in the view
- (void)fixToolbarWidth
{
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
    {
        float adjust = -10.5f;

        // self.toolbar is linked to the UIToolbar
        self.toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(adjust, 0, [SizeHelper getSizeInOrientation].width-adjust, self.toolbar.frame.size.height);

        // self.segmentedControl is linked to the UISegmentedControl
        self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.toolbar.frame.size.width+(adjust*2), self.segmentedControl.frame.size.height);
    }
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // fix on first load
    [self fixToolbarWidth];
}
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    // resize if they rotate the device
    [self fixToolbarWidth];
}
```

**UPDATED/SIMPLER VERSION**

As long as your toolbar and segmented controller are properly setup to scale the full width in the .xib file, you can just do the following in `viewDidLoad`

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
{
    // use a different adjustment for iPad vs iPhone/touch
    float adjust = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? -14.0f : -9.0f;
    self.toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(adjust, 0, self.toolbar.frame.size.width-adjust, self.toolbar.frame.size.height);
    self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.segmentedControl.frame.size.width+adjust, self.segmentedControl.frame.size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem,too. What I do is put the segment control out of toolbar. It's work for me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for answer that doesn't include fixing the width of segment, You need to use `Flexible Space` around the `Segmented Control` in the `UIToolbar`

[image]